# Euler's constant 'e' in italic in plot legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I'm new to Mathematica. I wrote the following code and got the output as follows
[image: Euler]

I cannot reproduce the code here as I don't know how to type 'e' in the blackboard font. I typed it in Mathematica by using the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

The problem is that in my input code, I've got an upright 'e' while in the plot legends, I've got an italic 'e'. Why does this happen and how to get an upright 'e' in the legend as well? I'm using Mathematica 12.0.0.0.

Comment: Try `StandardForm["\[ExponentialE]"]` in your plot legend instead of "e".

Comment: Quick (and perhaps uncorrelated) tip : Check from your notebook toolbar `Palettes>Basic Math Assistant> Typesetting`. You can find all symbols under the second column $\infty \beta$ and their keyboard shorcuts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that Mathematica use default options for plotting and labeling your graphics. On the case of plotting legends, by default Mathematica tries to print expressions in TraditionalForm. All this options can be customized. You can use StandardForm as follows:

```
Plot[\[EscapeKey]ee \[EscapeKey], {x, -5, 5},
 PlotLegends -> {StandardForm["\[EscapeKey]ee \[EscapeKey]]"]}]
```